# PHP get existing image from directory and copy

Tags: php, image, copy

I have a existing image in my directory and I want to copy that image and rename it. This is what I have in mind: open registraton.php -> load default picture inside registration.php -> copy default picture to username.jpg.

So how can i load the default image, copy and rename it?

I would think something like this:

```
$default = "Pictures/default.png";
$target = "Pictures/";
$newname = "$username.jpg";
$target = "$default . $newname";
```

But I know that dosent work at all, because it says it self. But what do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about what you're doing there.  If you need to copy a file, you need to use the copy function:

```
bool copy ( string $source , string $dest [, resource $context ] )
```

What you seem to be doing above is concatenating two strings.  So - in your code, you would just get a string with "Pictures/default.pngSomeName.jpg" in it.

Also, you can't just rename a PNG to a JPG - they are different formats: not just different extensions.

Comment: Yeah, I know that my stirng would be like that :P But was just giving a sample. But I got it to work ;) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that i understand you completely, my english is not that good.
But if you want to copy an image you should use copy($source, $dest) function.
if you want to rename a file/directory , you sould use rename($oldname, $newname) function.

Comment: Thanks, I just ended up using file_get_contents then fopen. But Thanks :)